# Embed json in ng-packagr

Tags: json, angular, ng-packagr

In an angular cli project, I managed to embed json like this

- add to `typings.d.ts`

```js
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

- import .json

```js
import * as data from '../assets/data.json';
```

But if I want to compile this into an Angular 5 module with ng-packagr, I get the following error:

> Error at .../.ng_pkg_build/my-module/ts/src/app/my-module.module.
>   ts:28:33: Cannot find module '../assets/data.json'.

Did anyone encountered this issue and knows how to solve it?

Comment: Struggling with the same issue now, have you solved it?

Comment: No, I didn't solved it. I will be looking if they introduced a similar functionality in Angular 6 and use that instead of ng-packagr.

Answer (score 0):

Ng-packagr in version [4.4.0](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#440-2018-10-21) finally added support for `resolveJsonModule`. See a [thread](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/1050) with this issue.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import jsonData from './angular.component.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'ng-component',
  template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>{{data}}',
  styleUrls: ['./angular.component.scss']
})
export class AngularComponent {
  @Input()
  title = 'Angular';

  data = jsonData;
}
```

Comment: I still get `Cannot find module '../assets/data.json'`

Comment: Please fill in your answer with the detailed info from here: https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/1131 and I'll vote it. Thanks!