# Specifying "resolveJsonModule": true When Running ng-packagr

Tags: angular, azure-devops, package.json, ng-packagr

I was given the requirement to include the version of my Angular 9 app as part of the HTML metadata.  The version number is obtained from

```
import { version } from '../../../package.json';
```

For both local and Azure DevOps pipeline build, we use ng-packagr.
For my local build, I can add resolveJsonModule to: node_modules\ng-packagr\lib\ts\conf\tsconfig.ngc.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...    
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
},
```

The pipeline build does npm install fresh wiping out all entries in node_modules on the Azure cloud build server.  So I cannot modify tsconfig.ngc.json on the cloud build server like I did for the local build.

Azure pipeline build step:

```
"packagr": "ng-packagr -p ng-package.json"
```

ng-package.json contents:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "public-api.ts"
  },
  "dest": "...",
  "whitelistedNonPeerDependencies": ["angular", "bootstrap", "font-awesome", "gojs", "wait-on", "jquery", "rxjs", "tslib", "uuid", "zone.js", "ngx-toastr", "watch", "onchange", "lodash", "hammerjs"]
}
```

Some of my unsuccessful attempts to force ng-packagr to use either a specified tsconfig.json or compilerOptions:

1) "All you need to do is amend tsconfig.lib.json under the library folder."  
https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/HEAD/docs/override-tsconfig.md

I tried adding tsconfig.lib.json under my own directory structure and then adding tsconfig.lib.json to my angular.json; but changes were not picked up.  Not sure if the github documentation meant adding/modifying the tsconfig.lib.json under node_modules\ng-packagr... ; if so:  
a) I could not find tsconfig.lib.json  
b) Even if I can find tsconfig.lib.json, this suggestion would still involve modifying contents under node_modules\ directory, which is wipe out with every pipeline build.

2) https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/HEAD/docs/configuration-locations.md  
I had a look at the schema of ng-package.json, but it does not allow for modifying compilerOptions:  
https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/src/ng-package.schema.json

3) "You need to provide a tsconfig via the command line using the -c."  
https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/1131

I expected the error:  
error TS2732: Cannot find module '../../../package.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension

to not show with -c tsconfig.app.json

```
ng-packagr -p ng-package.json -c tsconfig.app.json
```

and show when without -c tsconfig.app.json.  I could not even reproduce the error on my local without the change to tsconfig.ngc.json.

4) I have also read:  
[Embed json in ng-packagr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240081/embed-json-in-ng-packagr)  
https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/1050  
[How do I use my tsconfig file with ng-packagr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52273916/how-do-i-use-my-tsconfig-file-with-ng-packagr)  
[Include json file in ng-packagr build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50369248/include-json-file-in-ng-packagr-build)

But I could not find enough relevant info to solve my particular problem.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the config file to the build step:

```
"packagr": "ng-packagr -p ng-package.json --config tsconfig.lib.json"
```

The tsconfig.lib.json extends the default config and adds the compiler options:

```
{
   "extends": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/lib/ts/conf/tsconfig.ngc.json",
   "compilerOptions": {
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
   }
}
```